# How can I reference a version of a file in an S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an application that reads JSON files from S3 - older versions of my application need to reference corresponding older versions of the JSON files stored within S3 - is there a way to link (hard code) specific versions of the JSON files within S3?

I could just rename the JSON files by adding a version number to the JSON file name, but this seems unnecessary since S3 provides versioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each version of a versioned object has a unique version ID. If you have a file named dog.png in your version-controlled bucket then an HTTP GET of /dog.png will retrieve the latest but a GET of /dog.png?versionId=xyz will retrieve the object at version xyz.

Note that versions IDs look something like this: L4kqtJlcpXroDTDmpUMLUo.

See the [retrieving object versions documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetrievingObjectVersions.html) for more.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the version IDs for your files through the AWS cli as follows:

```bash
aws s3api list-object-versions \
 --bucket bucket-name \
 --prefix file-name
```

Result:

```
{
    "Versions": [
        {
            "ETag": "\"1357ec7c9be8bfed3965ac23456575d18\"",
            "Size": 33409,
            "StorageClass": "STANDARD",
            "Key": "filename",
            "VersionId": "Ec0OA9I.MqqNqFvyTPhMfCWEWu2Zwof8",
            "IsLatest": false,
            "LastModified": "2022-06-01T23:49:25+00:00"
        },
        {
            "ETag": "\"15342239383c52e165271f915ecf420d-3\"",
            "Size": 18693388,
            "StorageClass": "STANDARD",
            "Key": "filename",
            "VersionId": "7ZQHj2znv2RisLAwQHGEZKEX4nDo4IEM",
            "IsLatest": true,
            "LastModified": "2022-07-26T19:04:41+00:00"
        },
...
```